# Drupal 7 No Back button in session_store_example in Multi step forms Module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying create a multi-step form based on session_store_example from the mforms_examples module. But I am not able to figure it out how to add the Back button in this form.

All the other example forms were having back button except this one. Please help me to add a back button in this type form.

Comment: Would you add the relevant part of your code? I suspect that at present it will be hard for Drupal users to visualise the problem you are encountering, so if you can add more detail, it may help. (Aside: I would encourage you to refrain from noting how urgent the problem is, or asking for a full solution, since that does not always go down well with volunteers on the internet).

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in multistep module in drupal 7. I used a custom module and build a session_store multistep form with the help of mforms_example module. Except for the **session_store_example** store key, other forms like ajax_forms and  fs_store have the back button implemented.  Is there any way to add the previous button along with the next button in the session_store_example form.